# if statment to check if something exists otherwise UPDATE

Tags: php, xml, api, if-statement

I have an .xml page that i want to pull data from every 6 hours.

this data is then inserted into the database and the unique Key is set as "characterID".

the code then need to check for the following an perfom an action based on its results.

1. If the .XML file contains characterID not already in database add the row!
2. If the database contains a characterID NOT in the .XML remove row!
3. If a row in the .XML file is different (THE CHARACTERID wont be different but other data will) to the row in the database UPDATE the row with new information WHERE charactedID is the same!

[this](http://pastebin.com/he3DhSAB) is my current source code which loops through the XML and inserts the data correctly but i cannot update the information.

```
<?php
// INCLUDE DB CONNECTION FILE
include("includes/connect.php");

// CHANGE THE VALUES HERE
include("includes/config.php");

// URL FOR XML DATA
$url = "test.xml"; // For Testing Purposes

// RUN XML DATA READY FOR INSERT
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// RUN SQL to check data already in table
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from `ecmt_memberlist`");

// Loop Through Names
foreach ($xml->result->rowset[0] as $value) {

$characterID = mysql_real_escape_string($value['characterID']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($value['name']);
$startDateTime = mysql_real_escape_string($value['startDateTime']);
$baseID = mysql_real_escape_string($value['baseID']);
$base = mysql_real_escape_string($value['base']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($value['title']);
$logonDateTime = mysql_real_escape_string($value['logonDateTime']);
$logoffDateTime = mysql_real_escape_string($value['logoffDateTime']);
$locationID = mysql_real_escape_string($value['locationID']);
$location = mysql_real_escape_string($value['location']);
$shipTypeID = mysql_real_escape_string($value['shipTypeID']);
$shipType = mysql_real_escape_string($value['shipType']);
$roles = mysql_real_escape_string($value['roles']);
$grantableRoles = mysql_real_escape_string($value['grantableRoles']);


// NOW LETS INSERT INTO DATABASE!!
$query = "INSERT INTO `ecmt_memberlist` SET
characterID='$characterID',
name='$name',
startDateTime='$startDateTime',
baseID='$baseID',
base='$base',
title='$title',
logonDateTime='$logonDateTime',
logoffDateTime='$logoffDateTime',
locationID='$locationID',
location='$location',
shipTypeID='$shipTypeID',
shipType='$shipType',
roles='$roles',
grantableRoles='$grantableRoles'";

//echo query to error check
echo $query;
echo "<br><br>";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
};
?>
```

the table this gets inserted into will also hold some other information that will be associated with the characterID hence the need to "NOT REMOVE ROW AND REPLACE" else i will loose the associated data in that row when added manually.

Comment: This website here doesn't work well with asking for code. You are basically looking for a way to sync your database data with data from a different data-store, here the XML. It's probably best to solve the problem theoretically to get some ideas which code has to be written in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You could first do a `SELECT` statement with the CharacterID. Than you can check if the rowcount is equal to 1. If this is the case you can update your row, otherwise you insert a new row in the database.

Comment: how would i write the if statement to do the checks? im a php noob :p

Comment: ok i have written this,

http://pastebin.com/P5EahPVk

i just get "Query was empty" when trying to run.